# What is the name for a grey shaded effect on a photo and how do I achieve it in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I'm completely new to graphic work! I am looking to achieve the same grey shade effect on these images using GIMP.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello mstrchng, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you have tried and why it didn't work? We are not a tutorial-on-demand website, we ask you to show some effort and we'd rather explain where your process is wrong than give a quick step-by-step. Please [edit] your question to include this information. If you want to know more about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help], they will get you up to speed!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's just called an overlay.

You can achieve this effect by placing a black layer over top of your photo and changing the opacity until you get the level of dark you'd like. Works well with other colours than black too.

Changing the blending mode on the layer can add to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pictures, it see that the desaturation mostly happens on the light tones, so try something like this:

- Duplicate the layer
- `Color>Desaturate`
- `Layer>Mask>Add layer mask` and initialize to `Grayscale copy of layer`
- On the Mask, use Brightness/Contrast to increase both lightness (a bit) and contrast (some more)
- On the Layer, use Levels to reduce the output level of the whites.

Your layer stack will look like this:

[image: Layer stack]

And the result is:

[image: Result]